# Check if a specific range of values in one dataset exists in another dataset

Tags: microsoft-excel, find, comparison

I have two datasets, 1 and 2, each containing a number of columns with values. My end goal is to find all of the rows in dataset 1 that are different from and can't be found in dataset 2.

Dataset 1 (example):

```
Name        Species Age
Donald       Dog    3
Petronella   Dog    5
```

Dataset 2 (example):

```
Name        Species Age
Donald       Dog    3
Anna         Dog    5
```

In the example above, I would like to find out that the combination of cell values regarding Petronella are unique to the first dataset and can't be found in the second. Donald and Anna are of less interest in this case.

Perhaps an easy option would be to add a fourth column with a value of 1 or 0 depending on wether the range of data is present in the second dataset.

I know how to compare one range directly to another range, but how do I expand this comparison to include all of the rows in dataset 1? The order of the rows should not be a factor when determing if a range of values in dataset 1 can be found in dataset 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MATCH and CONCATENATE in an Array Formula to know the list of Unique Values from Dataset1. Since MATCH is used the comparison is not Case Sensitive though.

Sample Dataset1 is in cells B4:D7 & dataset2 is say in G4:I7.
Now in E4 put the following formula and then press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER from within the formula bar to create an Array Formula. The formula shall get enclosed in Curly Braces to indicate that it's any Array Formula.

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH((B4&C4&D4),CONCATENATE($G$4:$G$7,$H$4:$H$7,$I$4:$I$7),0)),"Unique","Duplicate")
```

See the below screenshot.
It's the basic use of MATCH but the argument is Concatenated List of Rows in an Array.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I have a problem executing this formula. I get the message where it asks me if I'm trying to execute a formula.

Comment: Please post the exact formula you are using and preferably a screenshot of the error. What Version of Excel are you using? What is a list separator in your case is it Comma or Semicolon?

Comment: No need =) After changing to semicolon it works like a charm. Thank you very much. The only downside is I wouldn't ever have been able to figure out how to achieve this result on my own ...

Answer (score 0):

Just add the function

```
=COUNTIF(range,criteria)
```

in that fourth column.

---

In your case the range would be cells containing

```
Donald
Anna
```

and the criteria would be the cell to be evaluated.

The output is 1 if there is a match and 0 otherwise.

Comment: This solution doesn't take into consideration the possibility that there may be more than one Donald or Anna. That's why I needed a formula that looks at the age and species as well (in this example).