# Excel check if combination of data exists in a certain range

Tags: microsoft-excel, comparison, findstr

See question 1337631
[Check if a specific range of values in one dataset exists in another dataset](https://superuser.com/questions/1337631/check-if-a-specific-range-of-values-in-one-dataset-exists-in-another-dataset?newreg=22c04077278044d7a41122dd9ffea5b8)

This solution works great, but what if you want to check WITHIN the same range?
Want to use this for 2 purposes: 
1) while inputting data to alert that a certain combination has already been entered (which might have a valid reason due to other data being different) 
2) To mark all duplicate records

To use this formula for the first purpose (input) I check in the range above the current entry. That works great, but does not allow purpose 2...

Anybody a suggestion to get a combination of it working? Should work when concatinating all except current row... But that's going the be a complicated alteration of the formula?

Comment: Use COUNTIFS() and compare the result with 1...

Answer (score 3):

Let us say that your sample data has 3 columns and is in cells C3:F7.

Now in F3 put the following formula and press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER from within the Formula Bar to create an Array Formula. The formula shall now be enclosed in curly braces automatically to indicate that it's an array formula.

Now drag it down up to the intended rows. The Unique or Duplicate Status of the row within the same table shall be indicated accordingly.

```
=IF(SUM(IF(C3&D3&E3=$C$3:$C$7&$D$3:$D$7&$E$3:$E$7,1,0))>1,"Duplicate","Unique")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

great alternative formula, except it drives the CPU up to 90% and causes the sheet to become unusable if you expand the formula to the following "open end range" to make it applicable for an expanding list ...

=IF(ISTEXT(D7);IF(SUM(IF(B7&C7&D7=$B:$B&$C:$C&$D:$D;1;0))>1;"Duplicate";"Unique");"")

Any solution for that to make it available? I now resticted it to rows 8-1000 and this works, but of course need to follow up the growth of the sheet!

Comment: This can be done using table objects, which automatically redefine their ranges when resized. For example, Dataset[Column1]&Dataset[Column2]&Dataset[Column3].